# Denavit Hartenberg Exercises

Tags: dh-parameters

I'm reading "Robot Modeling and Control" by Spong. It seems to me there are mistakes in the manual solutions provided by the authors. I came across the following two questions

[image]

In this answer I think there is no $d_3$. It should be zero. In the following question

[image]

In my solution $\alpha_2=-90^\circ$ not $90^\circ$ and $\theta_3 = 0^\circ$ not $-90^\circ$. I would love to hear your feedback. Also, if you are instructor, you may need to double check this.

Answer (score 0):

yes you are right in both models.

but add extending length of prismatic joint as it may be able to extend further
and add theta to revolute joints

[image: first model]

add d1+a1 in the place of d1 and so on

hope it helps

Comment: What DH conversion you're using? What is the table you've provided?

Comment: i think it is modified dh table. 
for reference:
[ link ](https://automaticaddison.com/how-to-find-denavit-hartenberg-parameter-tables/#The_Three_Steps)